# Defining a varying amount of object properties when using an object constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner trying to code a text adventure. My knowledge is limited so I feel I have to explain the whole of what I'm doing.

The game works around rooms. A large amount of rooms are made within an array (roomBase) through a room constructor (Room). Rooms are stored inside an array so the rooms can be shuffled. As the rooms have random positions, the room the player is in is copied to an object called currentRoom so the player/rest of code can interact with it. This system has worked for holding the description text of the rooms when the player enters one and true/falses whether there are enemies in the room, but as I try to implement a "look" command I can't figure out the right way to do it. Ideally, I'd like a varying amount of descriptions of "look"able things to be properties inside the room objects which can be copied and referenced in currentRoom. I can see how to do this in a single object, I'm just unsure how to do this when a constructor is involved.

Below is what the solution would be in an ideal world. Is there a way I can do something like this? Apologies for my noob question.

```
function Room(roomEntry,desc) {
   this.roomEntry = roomEntry;
   this.desc = {desc}
}

var roomBase = [
room0 = new Room(
"You enter a dark room. Vines cover the walls and you notice a hilt sticking out the ground.",
"sword:"With a closer look you find the sword is stuck.",vines:"Thick vines that you've never seen the likes of before."")
room1 = new Room()
room2 = new Room()
//etc
];

var currentRoom = new Object({});
currentRoom.roomEntry = "foo";
currentRoom.desc = {};

currentRoom = roomBase[0];

alert(currentRoom.desc.sword);
```

Comment: Your current code is invalid. Could you please fix the formatting and give a sample what youre meaning with `id like a varying amount of descriptions` , especially where youre going to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily pass an object to the constructor, like:

```
class Room {
  constructor(roomEntry, desc){
     this.roomEntry = roomEntry;
     this.desc = desc;
  }
}
```

So you can do:

```
new Room("whatever", { sword:"whatever", vines:"whatever"})
```